# Any advantage to escaping with LIKE over CHARINDEX for a non-sargable query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server, is there any advantage in terms of performance to use an escaped `LIKE` clause over `CHARINDEX`, or to use `CHARINDEX` over an escaped `LIKE` clause, when the query is known to be [non-sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) anyway? (Assuming full text search isn't enabled.)

For instance, these two `WHERE` clauses are effectively the same:

```
WHERE FieldName LIKE '%mum\%ble%' ESCAPE '\'
```

and

```
WHERE CHARINDEX('mum%ble', FieldName) > 0
```

Both look for the text `mum%ble` (literally) anywhere in the field. Since the `LIKE` starts with a wildcard, the engine can't use an index for it.

Is there any performance advantage to one of the other? (I can see a usage advantage to `CHARINDEX` [I don't have to make sure to escape things], but I'm curious about performance.)

I'm curious mostly for recent versions of SQL Server, say 2008+, if it matters.

Comment: _Slightly_ related if you haven't read: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46917/like-uses-index-charindex-does-not

Comment: @Tanner: Very much related, thank you. That link is very interesting, esp. the bit about how you can tell SQL Server to use the index even with `CHARINDEX`.

Comment: I know not the question but if you are doing a lot of this FullText may be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I tried on one data set and got identical execution plans for both with very similar metrics--the only difference was a truly insignificant increase in the cost of the CHARINDEX version.  I am guessing the optimizer treats these in the same way and does the almost same internal comparisons for both.